My keras CNN model gives good predictions in 10/11 classes but missleads to the 11th class. What can I do to improve?
My project involves classifying printed numerical characters from real-life essays. My dataset includes 11 classes ('0' - '10'), with the label '10' representing the '/' symbol.
The issue is that while my training dataset is balanced, the original size of the images for the class '/' is 28x28, whereas the others are 224x224. However, I resized all of them to 28x28 before training the CNN model.
Here are the results:
On the test dataset:
Accuracy: 85%
Confusion matrix:

On the real-life test dataset with 821 images:
Accuracy: 88%
Confusion matrix:

As you can see from the matrix, there is a significant misclassification of the label '10' (the '/' symbol) into labels '1' and '7'.
Specific issue:

I have tried the first solution suggested in a similar topic but it did not significantly improve the results.
Does anyone have any solutions or recommendations for this issue?
Thank you for your attention. I'm looking forward to your replies.

The lack of symmetry is interesting. Your model confuses "/" with "1" and "7", but never "1" or "7" with "/". In my view, it suggests that the lack of the beak on the top of the line, which allows us to discern "/" from "7", can't be recognized for some reason.
I would check the data first and look at "/" to see if they have correctly assigned labels. If all's fine, try adjusting the architecture to help the model note the missing part of the line that is a difference between "/" and "7". I would try doing experiments with:

different activation function
deeper network
some variations in layers like differences between the output of two layers

